# Can a pointer to base point to an array of derived objects?

Tags: c++, pointers

I went to a job interview today and was given this interesting question.

Besides the memory leak and the fact there is no virtual dtor, why does this code crash?

```
#include <iostream>

//besides the obvious mem leak, why does this code crash?

class Shape
{
public:
    virtual void draw() const = 0;
};

class Circle : public Shape
{
public:
    virtual void draw() const { }

    int radius;
};

class Rectangle : public Shape
{
public:
    virtual void draw() const { }

    int height;
    int width;
};

int main()
{
    Shape * shapes = new Rectangle[10];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        shapes[i].draw();
}
```

Comment: Besides the missing semicolon, you mean? (That would be a compile-time error, though, not runtime)

Comment: Are you sure they were all virtual ?

Comment: It Should be `Shape **` It's pointing to an array of Rectangles. Then the access should have been shapes[i]->draw();

Comment: Are the pointers in `shapes` supposed to be uninitialized?

Comment: @Bill, this is the question as asked; so not sure

Comment: @Tony out of curiosity, what happened when you couldn't answer it?

Comment: @Seth, well they told me what the answer was and why it was like that

Comment: @Seth, will know next week, would be awesome to get it, this is the kinda job I dream about :)

Comment: @Tony good luck then, keep us informed :)

Comment: @R. Martinho Fernandes- Ah, my mistake!  Sorry about that.  Thanks for fixing it!

Comment: The program is not compilable for more reasons than one. Some of these reasons (like `->` in `shapes[i]->draw()`) imply that the code in question is catastrophically misformed or misquoted. That alone makes the original question totally meaningless. This code **does not** crash. This code is ill-formed.

Comment: @AndreyT: The code is correct now (and was also correct originally). The `->` was a mistake made by an editor.

Comment: This might be a silly question, but where is the "obvious" memory leak?

Comment: I think it's the fact that the `Shape`s are never deleted. Might not count as a leak under some definitions, what with program termination and all that.

Comment: because it can (Murphy's law) :-)

Comment: @R. Martinho: I see. So to avoid the memory leak you'd have to explicitly dispose of the array of Shapes?

Comment: @Andy: yeah, `delete[] shapes` would do.

Comment: Did anyone else notice the fact that the `Shape` base class is missing a virtual destructor? Even if you add in the appropriate `delete` calls, it'll still leak memory.

Comment: @Mike Apparently you failed to notice that it says that in the can, er, question.

Answer (score 151, accepted):

You cannot index like that. You have allocated an array of `Rectangles` and stored a pointer to the first in `shapes`. When you do `shapes[1]` you're dereferencing `(shapes + 1)`. This will not give you a pointer to the next `Rectangle`, but a pointer to what would be the next `Shape` in a presumed array of `Shape`. Of course, this is undefined behaviour. In your case, you're being lucky and getting a crash.

Using a pointer to `Rectangle` makes the indexing work correctly.

```
int main()
{
   Rectangle * shapes = new Rectangle[10];
   for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) shapes[i].draw();
}
```

If you want to have different kinds of `Shape`s in the array and use them polymorphically you need an array of *pointers* to Shape.

Answer (score 39):

As Martinho Fernandes said, the indexing is wrong. If you wanted instead to store an array of Shapes, you would have to do so using an array of Shape *'s, like so:

```
int main()
{
   Shape ** shapes = new Shape*[10];
   for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) shapes[i] = new Rectangle;
   for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) shapes[i]->draw();
}
```

Note that you have to do an extra step of initializing the Rectangle, since initializing the array only sets up the pointers, and not the objects themselves.

Answer (score 14):

When indexing a pointer, the compiler will add the appropriate amount based on the size of what's located inside the array. So say that sizeof(Shape) = 4 (as it has no member variables). But sizeof(Rectangle) = 12 (exact numbers are likely wrong).

So when you index starting at say... 0x0 for the first element, then when you try to access the 10th element you're trying to go to an invalid address or a location that's not the beginning of the object.

Comment: As a non c++ adept, mentioning of the SizeOf() helped me understand what @R. Martinho was saying in his answer.

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7200917/1047213) by CB Bailey is more accurate from the point of view of language specification. It more clearly explains why accessing `shapes[i]` is undefined behavior. That answer is quoted below with the pointer variable changed to `shapes`, `Shape` as the base class and `Rectangle` as the derived class (instead of `p`, `Base` and `Derived` from that question).

> If you look at the expression `shapes[1]`, `shapes` is a Shape* (`Shape` is > a completely-defined type) and 1 is an int, so according to ISO/IEC
> 14882:2003 5.2.1 [expr.sub] this expression is valid and identical to
> `*((shapes)+(1))`.

Thus, accessing `shapes[i]` is not ill-formed. However, it is undefined as explained below.

> From 5.7 [expr.add] / 5, when an integer is added to a pointer, the
> result is only well defined when the pointer points to an element of
> an array object and the result of the pointer arithmetic also points
> the an element of that array object or one past the end of the array.
> `shapes`, however, does not point to an element of an array object, it
> points at the base class sub-object of a Derived object. It is the
> `Rectangle` object that is an array member, not the `Shape` sub-object.
>
> Note that under 5.7 / 4, for the purposes of the addition operator,
> the `Shape` sub-object can be treated as an array of size one, so
> technically you can form the address `shapes + 1`, but as a "one past the
> last element" pointer, it doesn't point at a `Shape` object and
> attempting to read from or write to it will cause undefined behavior.

These paragraphs give a very good idea of how the expression `shapes[i]` is dealt with.