# Weird output for array used with polymorphism

Tags: c++, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can a pointer to base point to an array of derived objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7196172/can-a-pointer-to-base-point-to-an-array-of-derived-objects)

I am practicing what learned and I tried the folowing:

```
#include <iostream>

struct S {
    S() : val(0) {}

    int val;
};

struct D : S {
    D() : val(1) {}

    int val;
};

void f(S *s) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++, s++)
        std::cout << s->val;
}

int main() {
    D d[5];
    f(d);
}
```

What I find weird is that the output is `01010` instead of `11111` like I expected. So it seems to be getting the `val` member from the `S` class instead of the `D` class on every other loop. But why?

Comment: BTW, the `f(s);` should be `f(d);`, right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because `s++` increments the pointer by the `sizeof(S)`, not `sizeof(D)`, yet `s` actually points to the array of `D` at run-time.

- The first iteration happens to be aligned with `S::val` of the first array element (which is 0),
- the second with `D::val` of the **first** element (which is 1),
- the third with the `S::val` of the second element (which is 0)
- and so on...

This is essentially an undefined behavior. If your classes looked differently (or a platform with different alignment was used), you'd receive different and even more baffling results.

If you don't need polymorphism, just declare the function to receive an array of `D` (not `S`). If you do need the polymorphism, you should consider using an array of (smart) pointers, instead of the array of concrete elements (and access the data through virtual functions instead of direct field access).

Comment: Great answer! But why is this undefined behavior?

Comment: @David Unfortunately, I'm not a standard-peeper, so I can't point you to the exact paragraph in the C++ standard that defines this (and I'm sure it's there!). Logically (and independently from C++), value arrays are not [covariant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)), only reference arrays are.