# Accessing a derived class through the reference of super class

Tags: c++, oop

I'm just a beginner on C++ and the object oriented stuffs. In transition from C. Please bear with my ignorance. This is in continuation with:

[Can a pointer to base point to an array of derived objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7196172/can-a-pointer-to-base-point-to-an-array-of-derived-objects)

```
#include <iostream>

//besides the obvious mem leak, why does this code crash?

class Shape
{
public:
    virtual void draw() const = 0;
};

class Circle : public Shape
{
public:
    virtual void draw() const { }

    int radius;
};

class Rectangle : public Shape
{
public:
    virtual void draw() const { }

    int height;
    int width;
};

int main()
{
    Shape * shapes = new Rectangle[10];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        shapes[i].draw();
}
```

The Class `Shape` contains a pure virtual function and hence it becomes an abstract class. Hence, on the first place, there should be a compiler error on creating an instance for it. But I don't get any compiler error.

Comment: can you post the code? we can't start answering without seeing what you've fed the compiler.

Comment: sorry, I did not paste because it was on the source link which I had mentioned..

Comment: You never create an instance of Shape. Where do you think you do?

Comment: btw: the code you've posted contains a bug... change the `Shape` into a `Rectangle`... check the accepted answer

Comment: Ok so, `Shape * shapes` just creates references and does not instantiate the Class Shape, hence there is no issue. Am I correct?

Comment: `Shape* Shapes` is a bug... but to your question, check the R-value... it is `= new Rectangle[10];` so you are created 10 objects of `Rectangle` not `Shape`. if the R-value was `= new Shape[10];` you'll get a compiler error of `trying to instantiate a pure virtual class`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed `Shape` contains a `pure virtual` method, but it is not instantiated.

the `main` function contains an instantiation of `Rectangle` which is not a pure virtual class. so there is no problem

```
int main()
{
    Rectangle * shapes = new Rectangle[10];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        shapes[i].draw();
}
```

-- I've re-post *R. Martinho Fernandes* code from that post accepted answer