# Pointer increments with children of abstract structs

Tags: c++

I'm trying to iterate over an array of structs, that are children of an abstract class, by incrementing the pointer to that struct.
This works until I add members to that struct, which then results in a memory access violation when trying to derefence the pointer.
Here's the code:

```
struct A {
    virtual float Get() = 0;
};

struct B : A {
    //int val;

    B() {
    // val = 0.f;
    }

    void Set(int v) {
        //val = v;
    }
    
    float Get() override{
        return 0.f; // val;
    }
};

struct C : A {
    A* previous;
    int numPrev;

    C() :
        previous(nullptr),
        numPrev(0)
    {}

    float Get() override {
        float v = 0.f;
        A* p = previous;
        for (int i = 0; i < numPrev; i++) {
            v += p->Get();
            p++;
        }
        return v;
    }

    void Register(A* prev, int count) {
        previous = prev;
        numPrev = count;
    }
};

C* c;
B* b;

int main()
{
    int count = 3;
    b = new B[count]();
    c = new C[count]();

    B* curB = b;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        curB->Set(i);
        curB++;
    }

    C* cur = c;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        cur->Register(b, count);
        cur++;
    }

    float res = 0.f;
    cur = c;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        res += c->Get();
        cur++;
    }

    std::cout << res;

    delete[] b;
    delete[] c;
}
```

The code above compiles and works fine (as far as I can tell) but if I uncomment all the "val"-stuff in struct B it suddenly throws the mentioned memory access violation.
I suspected that the cause might be that "p++" in the Get() method of struct C is incrementing by the wrong amount, because p is a pointer to A but we actually deal with Bs (which are children of A).
Adding the member "val" to B would then cause sizeof(B) != sizeof(A) and therefore p++ might not actually jump to the next element but rather "into" the current one causing the violation?
Unfortunately changing "p++" to either "p += sizeof(A)" or "p += sizeof(B)" does not solve this, so I'm starting to suspect it's something else...

Does anyone have an idea what could cause this?
Am I just blind to a dumb mistake or is there anything else going on?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: You are treating an array of `B` as if it were an array of `A`. Since `sizeof(A) != sizeof(B)` the pointer arithmetic inside the `Get` function moves the pointer to wrong addresses

Comment: Removed C tag. C doesn't have abstract structs.

Comment: **Never treat arrays polymorphically**: http://blog.sinzy.net/hjk41/entry/9315

Comment: Nice, thank you! That helps a lot! Does anyone of you know why p += sizeof(B) doesn't work though? I would have thought that this would then move the pointer to the correct adress?

Does anyone have a different idea? I tried to use vectors instead but then the problem is that I cant pass a pointer to vector<B> when vector<A>* is expected.
I'd like to use pointers to not copy around large arrays/vectors as performance is important here.
And I also cant use B as "previous" because C can either hold objects of type B or C as "previous".

I appreciate the help!

Comment: Never mind, using A** for c and b seems to solve this (if someone has the same problem). I took that method from Patrick Costello's answer under: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7196172/can-a-pointer-to-base-point-to-an-array-of-derived-objects

Comment: Re: `p += sizeof(B)` -- pointer arithmetic advances a pointer to point to the next element of its type. That is, `A*p = whatever; p++;` will increment `p` to point to the next `A`. Adding `sizeof(B)` to `p` treats `sizeof(B)` as the **number** of `A`s to skip.

Comment: @user253751 -- more to the point, C does't have inheritance. The problem here has nothing to do with `A` being abstract; the same things would happen if it wasn't.

Comment: @PeteBecker Oh that makes sense, thank you!
And my bad for adding "C" to the tags, I didn't know it doesn't have inheritance.